# multilevel mysql query with a weird setup

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a problem. I am a codding newbie and learning php and mysql as i go.
i am working on an application and ran into a problem that i cant figure out.

I have three tables:

category:

```
+-----------+----------+--------------------+
| id        | name     | sort |   active    |
+-----------+----------+--------------------+
|         1 | apple    |    1 |      1      |
|         2 | mango    |    2 |      1      |
|         3 | blueberry|    3 |      0      |
+-----------+----------+--------------------+
```

service :

```
+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------+
| id        | category_id | name   | sort |active| process_time |
+-----------+------+------+--------+------+------+--------------+
|         1 |     1       | slices |  1   |  1   |  2 hours     |
|         2 |     1       |  half  |  2   |  1   |  6 hours     |
|         3 |     2       | slices |  1   |  1   |  1   hour    |
|         4 |     2       | whole  |  2   |  1   |  6  hours    |
|         5 |     3       | bunch  |  1   |  0   |  12 hours    |
|         6 |     3       | a lot  |  2   |  1   |  10 hours    |
+-----------+------+---------+------+-------------+-------------+
```

user_price:

```
+-----------+----------+------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id        | user_id  | 1    |   2   |   3     |    4    |    5    |    6    |    
+-----------+----------+------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|         1 | 20       |    1 |   1   |   5     |    4    |    6    |    6    |
|         2 | 22       |    2 |   1   |   2     |    3    |    5    |    1    |
|         3 | 32       |    3 |   2   |   7     |    4    |    1    |    3    |
+-----------+----------+------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Categories have the categories that i sell in my store.
Services have the services that i offer in my store they correspond to the categories and are unique to only that category.
Prices have the user prices that i charge my customers every user has a different price the column names in the price table correspond to the services id.

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3a42)** with sample data

Now here is the problem, in one sweep i would like to get a row that contains columns from all three tables for user_id 22 (user_id is only used for prices)

```
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+
| service_id    | category_name  | service_name    |   process_time   |   price   |  
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+
|  3            |  mango         | slices          |   1 hour         |    2      |
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+
```

Any ideas???

Comment: Please make the question less and help others able to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT s.id service_id, 
       c.name category_name, 
       s.name service_name, 
       s.process_time, 
       p.`3` price
  FROM service s JOIN category c
    ON s.category_id = c.id JOIN user_price p
    ON p.user_id = 22
 WHERE s.id = 3
```

Output:

```
| SERVICE_ID | CATEGORY_NAME | SERVICE_NAME | PROCESS_TIME | PRICE |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3 |         mango |       slices |       1 hour |     2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/415d72/1)** demo

---

Now while it's not too late please normalize your `user_price table`. That will save you a lot of headache in the long run.

Your renewed schema for this table might look like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_price
(
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    user_id int(11) NOT NULL, 
    service_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    price decimal(19,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (service_id) REFERENCES service (id),
    UNIQUE KEY  (user_id, service_id) 
);
```

And the proper query using this table

```
SELECT s.id service_id, 
       c.name category_name, 
       s.name service_name, 
       s.process_time, 
       p.price
  FROM service s JOIN category c
    ON s.category_id = c.id JOIN user_price p
    ON s.id = p.service_id 
   AND p.user_id = 22 
 WHERE s.id = 3
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b2b2/1)** demo. *In this example the table has been named `user_price1` to show you both queries side-by-side.*

Comment: @user1069334 Consider to normalize your `user_price` table. See updated answer for details.